# Left-align a <div> to a centered <div> with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a web page with several `<div>` blocks styling them with CSS according to the following diagram. However I have no clue how to get this done. I have tried both variants as suggested by the answers (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26599439/478406 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598329/478406) but I think I'm missing something.

[image]

Comment: Do you want this to be responsive as well?

Comment: Fahad Yes, this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML and CSS below should do what you want, if I understand what you're asking correctly.

Note that `display:inline-block` allows the two `div` elements to sit next to each other, so you can set their `text-align` independently. Also, because of the `inline-block` property the elements will wrap when the screen size becomes smaller.

http://jsfiddle.net/k6y8asbk/

```
.message-text{
    text-align:left;
    display:block;
}

.some-text,
.my-list{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:top;
}

.my-list{
    text-align:center;
}

ul{
    margin-top:0px;   
}

<div id='message-container'>
    <div class='message-text'>Message Text</div>
    <div class='some-text'>Some text</div>
    <div class='my-list'>
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @GaryLuck. I have tried your idea but it's not quite what I'm looking for. Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/cd4trrjy/7. 1) The "Some items..." shoudld align vertically with the first item in the list. 2) The complete block with "Some items..." and the item list is not left-aligned to the welcome message. Maybe you could have another look?

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you mean @Robert. I forked your jsFiddle, is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/k6y8asbk/

Comment: Thanks @Gary. That's exactly what I'm looking for. I have modified your jsfiddle a little bit but basically you got the point :-)

Comment: Perfect! I've updated the answer to reflect the JSFiddle I posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think to accomplish something like this, you'd need to wrap everything in a container with `text-align: center`, then wrap the message in a span with `display: inline-block` and `position: relative`. This will allow the first line of text to determine the width of the block-level element, while still being centered in the outer container. Since we set position to relative, we can now create a child element to be aligned to the left edge of the first line with a `position: absolute`.

[Here is a jsfiddle as a proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/steve_n/cd4trrjy/2/)

Noe: Absolute position takes the element out of the stack order, so anything below will collapse up. This means that if the first line is too short, the second line will overlap with the list (but that would be an issue regardless, as the list is supposed to be centered). If the list doesn't need to be centered perfectly, you could include it inside the child element that is positioned absolute and adjusted the list's positioning as needed.